# Get value of ImageView from ListView after clicking in Android Dialog

Tags: android, listview

I want get value from a `ListView` item after clicking, I can get the value of `TextView` from `ListView` item, but I can't get image value of `ImageView` from `ListView`after clicking. Please help me.

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
        //getting value from listview after click

        String nm = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuKuNama)).getText();
        int gbr = (int) ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.ivMenuKuImg)).getId();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.detail_menu);
        //inisialisasi menu item

        ImageView detailImg = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.detailMenuImg);
        TextView detailNamaMenu = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.detailNamaMenu);
        detailNamaMenu.setText(nm);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(NurHelper.BASE_URL_IMAGE +gbr, detailImg);

        dialog.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Be specific. What 'value' of ImageView do you want to get? An specific attribute or the reference to the ImageView? Are you getting an error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I wan get title Image from listView, I don't getting error but i get null value